# is there is any possibility to save all the bookmarks of a scorm content and reuse it in next login session?

Tags: c#, scorm

I am using Scorm player in my website to show the course but is there any possibilities that to store the current progress of a member and show the content  which would come in next login.

basically i want to store the progress and use it in next time to tell user you cover this much area.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can certainly do this, but it requires you to program your SCO to save the data and read it back on the next launch. You should save this data in the cmi.location or cmi.suspend_data field via the SCORM API. You also need to make sure that your run-time data is preserved for the next launch by setting cmi.exit to "suspend" to ensure that the LMS doesn't start a new attempt on the next launch.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Mike's response, your content would do the following when launched a second time:

1. Initialize the API
2. Get the location data by calling a get function through the API
3. Display the correct content based on what was received from that get

Mike's giving you the SCORM 2004 commands. Be aware that there are SCORM 2004 and SCORM 1.2 commands and in some systems you'll want to use SCORM 1.2 rather than 2004.